# Why does inline XMLHttpRequest start after later external <script> requests?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have an inline XMLHttpRequest in my `<head>` just to see if I can make it be the first request issued from the browser (after the main html file).  Immediately following that request, I have an external  resource:

```
<head>
    <script>
        ...some code...
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/get_data');
        ...etc...
        xhr.send();
    </script>
    <script src="/some/other/file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Why, in the network tab of chrome developer tools, does the request for file.js start *before* the request to /get_data?

Comment: Because XMLHttpRequest as default is asynchronous, and Scripts as default are synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XMLHttpRequest() gets handle by XHR API. Which runs after the browser takes care of lower level tasks. So I guess the external script does not have any networking tasks in it. If it did they would be called after the first XMLHttpRequest() but not necessarily complete first since they are asynchronous tasks.

The real reason for XHR is to handle asynchronous networking data requests from client to server.

Basic scripted tasks will be completed in order listed, by the browser at browser basic processing level in the order you would expect. The XHR API kicks in when they are done.

Here is a good reference link to XHR API
https://hpbn.co/xmlhttprequest/

Below is a good excerpt from it.

XHR is an application API provided by the browser, which is to say that the browser automatically takes care of all the low-level connection management, protocol negotiation, formatting of HTTP requests, and much more:

The browser manages connection establishment, pooling, and termination.

The browser determines the best HTTP(S) transport (HTTP/1.0, 1.1, 2).

The browser handles HTTP caching, redirects, and content-type negotiation.

The browser enforces security, authentication, and privacy constraints.

And more…

Free from worrying about all the low-level details, our applications can focus on the business logic of initiating requests, managing their progress, and processing returned data from the server. The combination of a simple API and its ubiquitous availability across all the browsers makes XHR the "Swiss Army knife" of networking in the browser.

Closing note : 
You can always put your Get request in a .js file it will be processed prior to the other file but again all the basic HTML and other browser basics tasks and processing in both files will be completed prior to XHR API kicks in.